# Dependency Exception for String and lang class in Stuts 2 with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration, struts2

I am using Struts 2 and Spring 3. I can not inject the bean and getting `RunTimeException` on  starting `struts2` filter . I am using the following jar files

> servlet-api-2.4.jar, struts2-spring-plugin-2.1.6.jar,
>   struts2-spring-plugin-2.1.6.jar,
>   org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.M3.jar, xwork-2.0.2.jar,
>   struts2-core-2.0.12.jar, etc.

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.DependencyException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=java.lang.String, name='struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire.alwaysRespect'] in public org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.ServletContext).
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:290)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$2.call(ContainerImpl.java:117)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$2.call(ContainerImpl.java:115)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:542)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.injectStatics(ContainerImpl.java:114)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder.create(ContainerBuilder.java:494)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reload(DefaultConfiguration.java:145)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:52)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:205)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4071)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.DependencyException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=java.lang.String, name='struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire.alwaysRespect'] in public org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.ServletContext).
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:136)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:49)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:431)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:446)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:48)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:288)
        ... 28 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.DependencyException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=java.lang.String, name='struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire.alwaysRespect'] in public org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.ServletContext).
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:464)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:501)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:549)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:499)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:134)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.DependencyException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=java.lang.String, name='struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire.alwaysRespect'] in public org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.ServletContext).
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:327)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$5.create(ContainerImpl.java:299)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$5.create(ContainerImpl.java:298)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache$CallableCreate.call(ReferenceCache.java:155)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.internalCreate(ReferenceCache.java:81)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.get(ReferenceCache.java:121)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getConstructor(ContainerImpl.java:562)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:460)
        ... 38 more
    Caused by: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=java.lang.String, name='struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire.alwaysRespect'] in public org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.ServletContext).
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.createParameterInjector(ContainerImpl.java:239)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParametersInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:229)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:318)
        ... 47 more
    5 Mar, 2013 6:14:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
    SEVERE: Error filterStart
    5 Mar, 2013 6:14:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
    SEVERE: Context [/Fundation] startup failed due to previous errors
    5 Mar, 2013 6:14:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    5 Mar, 2013 6:14:01 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
    SEVERE: The web application [/Fundation] registered the JDBC driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
    5 Mar, 2013 6:14:01 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
    SEVERE: The web application [/Fundation] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
    5 Mar, 2013 6:14:01 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
    SEVERE: The web application [/Fundation] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@7f162a9c]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.InternalContext[]] (value [[Lcom.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.InternalContext;@847a8f3]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
    5 Mar, 2013 6:14:02 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
    INFO: validateJarFile(D:\eclipse-indigo\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\SpringMVCTutorial\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.4.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
    5 Mar, 2013 6:14:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'SpringMVCTutorial'
    5 Mar, 2013 6:14:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
    INFO: FrameworkServlet 'SpringMVCTutorial': initialization started
    5 Mar, 2013 6:14:02 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@1b83ee9a: display name [WebApplicationContext for namespace 'SpringMVCTutorial-servlet']; startup date [Tue Mar 05 18:14:02 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
    5 Mar, 2013 6:14:02 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SpringMVCTutorial-servlet.xml]
    5 Mar, 2013 6:14:02 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
    INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@1b83ee9a]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@12f53870
    5 Mar, 2013 6:14:02 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
    INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@12f53870: defining beans [viewResolver,/welcome.htm,springMessage,message]; root of factory hierarchy
    5 Mar, 2013 6:14:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
    INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome.htm] onto handler [com.cpt.spring.HelloWorldController@1aad40a0]
    5 Mar, 2013 6:14:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
```

Comment: So? What is your problem? Really: Please read [ask]

Comment: it shows error for lang and string injection. How would i solve

Comment: You still haven't read [ask], right? We would like you to spend more effort on writing a useful question. Only fair, since you want us to spend some effort on helping you.

Comment: You are probably mixing dependency versions; please include the jars you're deploying or the related portions of your pom file.

Comment: Your libraries are messed up. Check EVERY library, ensure the versions are compatible between each others and that you don't have multiple versions of a library in the classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to upgrade your `struts2` core  jar and `xwork` jar with the latest one. there may be an issue for using the different versions of stuts2core and struts2spring jar.

Hope this may be helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

Change the servlet spec to at least 2.4, also the spring plugin should be used with spring libs. if it doesn't help use constant `struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire.alwaysRespect=false` that is by default.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this problem. You first extract the struts-spring plugin. Inside `struts2-spring-plugin-x.y.z.jar\org\apache\struts2\spring` you will find the `StrutsSpringObjectFactory.class`. Using any class editor you can open this .class file.

There you will see that the line 
    @Inject(value=StrutsConstants.STRUTS_OBJECTFACTORY_SPRING_AUTOWIRE_ALWAYS_RESPECT,required=false)

String alwaysAutoWire is present. At the end,the method call

```
this.setAlwaysRespectAutowireStrategy("true".equalsIgnoreCase(alwaysAutoWire));
```

is present which causes the problem. Actually this method call cannot be mapped to a valid setter method, hence the `NoSuchMethodError`.

Now, to solve the problem download struts2-spring-plugin-2.0.11.1.jar and then add it to lib of project. If you follow the above process and inspect this jar you will not find that setter call and hence no error occurs. hope it works for you.